# Converting SQL Server recovery model simple to full

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with a recovery model of `simple`.

Monthly we have

- Total number of insert is 2196716
- Total number of delete is  639542
- Total number of update is 4203398

Now we are changing this server to active – active cluster environment.

Automatically recovery model change to full.

Above count’s are fine with recovery model fine? Any action required to take?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: With the full recovery model, you need to ensure that you need to take log backups frequently enough that you can both meet your recovery objectives and not run out of disk space.  If you're not taking log backups at all at the moment, you should start.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info